# Recyclerview scrollToPosition doesn't work with NestedScrollView ? Is there anyway?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

So I have a `Recyclerview` within a `NestedScrollView`. When I say `recycleview.scrollToPosition(X)` or `recycleview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(X)` it doesn't work at all.

If I move the `recycleview` out from the `nestedScrollView` it works fine, but I can't do it, because of the layout structure! Any idea?

```
scrollingView.requestChildFocus(recyclerView,recyclerView);
```

tried this, but not focusing on a certain position

Comment: Have you tried `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)`?

Comment: it will not work. my recyclerview is inside of nestedscrollview.

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604638/6798 Have a look at this solution.

Answer (score 3):

make your recyclerview like this

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/ll2"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_margin="5dp"
              android:clipToPadding="false"
              android:visibility="visible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**and the java code**

```
ItemsArrayList.add(0, items5);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView,false);
NestedScrollView nestedScrollingView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollingView);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll2);
float y = fcRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).getY();
float z =linearLayout.getY();
nestedScrollingView.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) z);
```

Comment: it will not work. my recyclerview is inside of nestedscrollview.

Comment: did you set setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) to your recyclerview

Comment: @BincyBaby try last option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149673/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-bincy-baby).

Comment: It does not work in my case. I get value of z as "0" every-time.

Comment: @Kuls can share more information about this so i can  try to help you

Comment: I have used nestedScrollView > LinearLayout > RecycleView in my XML. I have tried your snippet I get proper Y position and I get 0 value for "Z"