# Recycleview scroll to a position not working inside Nestedscrollview

Tags: android

I have implemented a recycleview inside a nested scroll view. But recycle view scroll to position methods are not working.

Below is my sample code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">


  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/list_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

 </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

below is the method for scrolling

```
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(this) {
                @Override
                protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                    return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
                }
            };
            smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(pos);
            recyclerView.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

Comment: but why you have used RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?

Comment: because I have some other views outside recycleview

Comment: @Darshana test try `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView,false);` and than  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45190337/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod not working for me

Comment: @Darshana how to resolve this issue ? if you getting a solution post your answer Thank You!

Comment: @HardikVasani refer the answer that I have posted

Comment: @Darshana Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how I resolve this issue

first get recycle view position that need to scroll using below method

```
final float y = recyclerView.getChildAt(selectedItem.getPos()).getY();
```

Then scroll nested scroll view to that position

```java
nestedScrollingView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        nestedScrollingView.fling(0);
                        nestedScrollingView.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) y);
                    }
                });
```

Don't forget to add `android:fillViewport="true"` on nestedscrollview

Comment: thanks for this, it works for me with an additional step:  `final float y = recyclerView.getY() + recyclerView.getChildAt(adapterPosition).getY();
        scrollView.post(() -> {
            scrollView.fling(0);
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) y);
        });`

Answer (score 8):

The thing is that you need to scroll the NestedScrollView, not the RecyclerView. E.g:

```
final float y = recyclerView.getChildAt(selectedItem.getPos()).getY(); 

scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, y)
```

Comment: I've tried everything on this site and this is the one solution that finally worked for me. It's very easy to forget that NestedScrollView controls the scrolling and get confused. Small edit: y now needs to be an "int" instead of float.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:title="Scroll">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Remove the NestedScrollView and add

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to your Recyclerview.Then ScrollToPosition works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extenstion function.

```
fun RecyclerView.nestedScrollTo(position:Int,nestedScrollView: NestedScrollView) {
    val y = getChildAt(position).y

    nestedScrollView.fling(0)
    nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,y.toInt())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    recyclerview.scrollToPosition(position);
}
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked like this.

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                        binding.nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(
                            0,
                            binding.recyclerview.measuredHeight,
                            500
                        )
                        // binding.nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, binding.recyclerview.measuredHeight)
                        // binding.nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, binding.recyclerview.measuredHeight)
                    }, 50L)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

It may solve your problem.

Comment: "When your RecyclerView is inside a NestedScrollView, its listener no longer works."