# Android - RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView - How to bring specified adaptor position with given offset (to top of NestedScrollView)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a Fragment with structure:

```
<NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ...>

        <View>

        <View>

        <RecyclerView />
    </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

I want to bring specified adapter position with given offset (in my case, bring to top of screen). I do following this post

[Recycleview scroll to a position not working inside Nestedscrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464418/recycleview-scroll-to-a-position-not-working-inside-nestedscrollview/51017902#51017902)

but it isn't working for me. I think it make "scroll to position" but not "bring position to top".

I want a statement such us `scrollToPositionWithOffset` for `NestedScrollView`.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.